# Что делают эти строки в react коде?

Tags: javascript

Прошу помочь понять некоторые вещи в коде, что они делают. Я закоментировал непонятные строки.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
 data: [],
 };

    this.setState(
      {
        data, shift: Object.keys(data)[0]             // (1)   
      }, this.filter                                               // (2)
    );
  };

  onClick = ({
    target: {                                                   //(3)
      dataset: { shift }
    }
  }) => {
    this.setState(() => ({ shift }), this.filter);            // (4)
  };

  render() {
    const { search, shift, data, filteredData } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
     {days.map((day, i) => (
          <button
            key={day}
            onClick={() => this.loadDay(i)}                                  // (5)
            className={i === this.state.day ? "active" : ""}
          >
            {day}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Вопросы:

1) `Object.keys(data)[0]` -это возвращает название первого свойства обьекта data в виде массива?

2) Почему в `setState` вторым параметром передается метод `filter`? что он делает в данный момент?

3) Зачем в метод `onClick` передан обьект `target`? И что он делает?

4) Опять же почему здесь снова вторым параметром передается метод `filter`?

5) Почему в атрибут `onClick` передают анонимную функцию `() => this.loadDay(i)`, а не просто метод `this.loadDay?`

Comment: Несколько строк?

Comment: исправил вопрос, ну 5 вопросов, не создавать же на каждый вопрос тему, подскажите что-нибудь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Object.keys(data)[0] -это возвращает название первого свойства
>   обьекта data в виде массива?

Возвращает первый ключ (элемент [0] массива ключей)

> 2) Почему в setState вторым параметром передается метод filter? что он
>   делает в данный момент?

Вторым параметром в `setState` передается функция, которая должна быть выполнена гарантировано после полного изменения `state`. Поскольку в `filter` тоже используется `setState`, то может возникнуть ситуация, когда `filter` изменит состояние раньше. Чтобы этого избежать, он передается вторым параметром

> 3) Зачем в метод onClick передан обьект target? И что он делает?

`target` - это объект элемента, на котором произошел клик и содержит его аттрибуты

> 4) Опять же почему здесь снова вторым параметром передается метод
>   filter?

Видимо в логике вашего приложения `filter` должна вызываться после каждого изменения состояния

> 5) Почему в атрибут onClick передают анонимную функцию () =>
>   this.loadDay(i), а не просто метод this.loadDay?

Потому что в неё надо передать переменную `i`, существующую только внутри коллбека `map`